# Windows 8 XAML bind byte[] to Image control?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to bind the byte[] in an image control but there is some issue in the Converter. Please let me know how can i fix this?
I am getting error on line  `stream.WriteAsync(bytesArray.AsBuffer());` as there is no AsBuffer function in byte[]. How should i fix this?

code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            byte[] bytesArray;

            if (value != null && value is byte[] && (value as byte[]).Length > 0)
            {
                bytesArray = value as byte[];
            }
            else
            {
                //TODO: Add default Image here
            }

            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                stream.WriteAsync(bytesArray.AsBuffer());
                stream.Seek(0);
                image.SetSource(stream);
                return image;
            }
        }
```

XAMl Code:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=OnlineBooksDetail[0].ImageSource, Converter={StaticResource ByteToBitmapImageConverter}}" Width="407" Height="542">
                        </Image>
```

Comment: In WPF you cand bind `byte[]` directly to `Source`, does this not work in WindowsRuntime?

Comment: ok that is why i need a converter. Can you provide some help update one I have written or some other way to achieve this?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with WindowsRuntime, and hve no idea what is in there, does it have `MemoryStream`

Comment: Yes it does. I have converted the byte[] to MemeoryStream like: MemoryStream  memoryStream = new MemoryStream (bytesArray). But now the challenge is that how can i write the memory stream to BitmapImage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue by creating Converter as written below. The below is working. Do let me know if I can improve it anyway.

Code:
 BitmapImage image;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the specified value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">Type of the target.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The parameter.</param>
    /// <param name="language">The language.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        byte[] bytesArray = null;

        if (value != null && value is byte[] && (value as byte[]).Length > 0)
        {
            bytesArray = value as byte[];
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: Add default Image here
        }

        using (MemoryRandomAccessStream memoryStream = new MemoryRandomAccessStream(bytesArray))
        {
            this.image = new BitmapImage();
            this.SetImageSource(memoryStream);
            return image;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the image source.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="memoryStream">The memory stream.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.NotImplementedException"></exception>
    private async void SetImageSource(MemoryRandomAccessStream memoryStream)
    {
        await this.image.SetSourceAsync(memoryStream);
    }
```